# Conflicting Generic Types between interdependant classes

Tags: java, generics, junit

I am attempting to write JUnit tests for my Expression Tree. The tree is composed of BaseExpressionTree< ValueType> (terminal nodes), ExpressionOperator< T> (non-terminal nodes), and CompositeExpressionTree< ValueType> (Sub Trees).

The Data Structure is supposed to be compatible with String, Double, and List< String> or List< Double> as BaseExpression (terminal leaves).

The classes are implemented with generics. there were no problems with the Double and String implementations, however List< String> and List< Double> implementations are causing conflicts with the Generics.

The heart of the problem is the ListOperator constructor. ListOperator is ment to represent operations on structures such as ArrayList and LinkedList. I would like to declare the class as following:

```
public class ListOperator<List<T>> implements ExpressionOperator<List<T>>{
```

...

but instead I can only declare it as follows:

```
public class ListOperator< T> implements ExpressionOperator<List<T>>{
    // a private field to store the String or Double operator to be used on the lists
    private ExpressionOperator<T> scalarOperator;

    /**
     * a constructor that takes one expression operator and stores it in the scalarOperator variable
     * @param       operator        an operation to be executed on a set of List operands
     */
    public ListOperator (ExpressionOperator<T> operator){
        this.scalarOperator=operator;
    }
}
```

basically the < T> in ListOperator (which represents a List) is conflicting with the < T>  in ExpressionOperator (which is supposed to represent what is inside the list).

Eclipse gives the following error output:

```
The constructor ListOperator<List<Double>>(DoubleOperator) is undefined
```

Is there a solution that doesn't involve using wild cards? The homework instructions were fairly explicit, the generics for class definitions are how they were described in the prompt.

I could use wild cards in the constructor parameters, but so far I haven't been able to do this.

```
    public ListOperator (? extends ExpressionOperator<T> operator){
```

and

```
    public ListOperator (< ? extends ExpressionOperator<T>> operator){
```

both give errors.

Comment: You would have to make the constructor accept wildcard based arguments like `<? extends ExpressionOperator<ValueType>`, otherwise, it could only accept `ExpressionOperator<ValueType>` values. The same applies for other types too.

Comment: Do you mean ExpressionOperator<? extends ValueType> or <? extends ExpressionOperator<ValueType>>? in either case, If I have methods that have generic expressions must they also have wildcard arguments?

Comment: Can you give the declaration of `DoubleOperator`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem has to do with using `ArrayList<Double>` for the `ValueType` type parameter, instead of `List<Double>`, which results in a conflict with `ListOperator`.

Try using `List<Double>` everywhere instead of `ArrayList<Double>`.

UPDATE:

Your `ListOperator` class should look like

```
public class ListOperator<T> implements ExpressionOperator<List<T>> { 
    // unchanged
  ...
  public ListOperator(ExpressionOperator<T> operator) {
    ...
  }
}
```

and you should be invoking it as `new ListOperator<Double>(myDoubleOperator)`.

Comment: I tried that, but still experienced the same problem. however I've narrowed it down to the preceding line. I listed the new Eclipse output above.

Comment: The code you've provided above looks perfectly fine.  Your problem isn't in that code.

Comment: The constructor for ListOperator< T> wants a ExpressionOperator< T>. When I pass in DoubleOperator< T> implements ExpressionOperator< T> it fails. How do I modify the constructor to accept different instantiations of ExpressionOperator< T>

Comment: Can you tell us more about `DoubleOperator`?  Is it an `ExpressionOperator<Double>`, or an `ExpressionOperator<List<Double>>`?

Comment: DoubleOperator implements ExpressionOperator<Double>. its class line is: public class DoubleOperator implements ExpressionOperator<Double>{

Comment: Perhaps I should change it to DoubleOperator<Double> implements ExpressionOperator<Double>?

Comment: Nope.  That would be a _terrible_ idea and lead to even more confusing bugs.  I've updated my answer based on what you've told us.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10577/discussion-between-louis-wasserman-and-ocasta-eshu)

Comment: The change to invocation definitely solved the problem. Thank you Louis, I appreciate your assistance!